# Chatter Threads not shown in debug logs

Tags: apex, chatter, feeditem, feedcomment

I've been developing an OOO auto-reply for my org so that when, for example, user A @mentions user B (who is on vacation) - user A will get auto chatter response from user B that he/she is on vacation. (See image below)

I wrote a method on the FeedItem trigger. It works fine as long as the chatter is an original posting. However, it does not work when the chatter is part of a thread.

I looked at the debug logs when chattering into a thread, but produced ZERO logs.

Does anyone know what is going on here? Would it be possible to write a trigger action on chatter threads?

Best,
Eric

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your trigger is only being fired upon the insertion of a FeedItem. You need to write a similar trigger for [FeedComment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feedcomment.htm) insertion.